# Standardized test output format

Tags: java, c, testing

Is there some (ad-hoc-) standard output format for test output (system tests, not unit tests, and not tied to a particular testing environment)? Existing C and Java bindings would be nice, but I'm mainly interested in the output format.

The only thing I found was [TAP](http://testanything.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page#TAP_Development); it seems to fit my requirements, but does not seem to be used very much, which makes me think that there is probably a more widespread solution.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to check systems tests in the same way as unit test, i.e. using a program.  You have production systems tests themselves on startup and in Java's case warmup the critical code.  If you want automated checking, you shouldn't need to read the text logs of a file to determine it is behaving correctly.

Comment: I want to inspect the test output programmatically. I'm just interested if there's a widely adopted output format for environment agnostic tests.

Comment: In my experience the best tests are very application and functionality specific.  I am not sure what the value of platform generic tests and outputs would be.